# In R is there a way to create a new column based on column names and values? Tidy solution welcome

Tags: r, dplyr

Specifically I have an untidy data.frame with subspecies varieties in separate columns, like this;

```
# Data
Genus<- c("Metrosideros", "Gahnia", "Acacia")
Species<- c("polymorpha", "aspera", "koa")
Subspecies<- c("", "globosa","")
Variety<- c("glaberrima", "", "")
df<-data.frame(Genus, Species, Subspecies, Variety)
```

But I want a new column that looks like this;

```
df$Sciname<- c("Metrosideros polymorpha var. glaberrima",
               "Gahnia aspera subsp. globosa",
               "Acacia koa")
```

There is probably a clever solution using `paste()` and `ifelse()` but I cannot figure it out. If there is a tidyverse (dplyr) solution that is welcome. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get there with `paste()` and a little bit of indexing.

```
with(df, paste(
  Genus,
  Species,
  c("", "subsp.")[(Subspecies != "") + 1],
  Subspecies,
  c("", "var.")[(Variety != "") + 1],
  Variety
))

[1] "Metrosideros polymorpha   var. glaberrima" "Gahnia aspera subsp. globosa   "           "Acacia koa    "
```

You can use `stringr::str_squish()` on the result to get rid of unwanted spaces which will give:

```
[1] "Metrosideros polymorpha var. glaberrima" "Gahnia aspera subsp. globosa"            "Acacia koa"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option with `tidyverse`, where we can add the additional strings to the `Subspecies` and `Variety` columns, then we can use `unite` to combine all columns. Then, we can clean up the `Sciname` column then rejoin to the original dataframe.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(Subspecies = ifelse(Subspecies != "", paste0("subsp. ", Subspecies), Subspecies),
         Variety = ifelse(Variety != "", paste0("var. ", Variety), Variety)) %>%
  unite("Sciname", Genus:Variety, sep = " ", remove = FALSE, na.rm = T) %>%
  select(Sciname) %>%
  mutate(Sciname = trimws(Sciname)) %>%
  bind_cols(df, .)
```

**Output**

```
         Genus    Species Subspecies    Variety                                  Sciname
1 Metrosideros polymorpha            glaberrima Metrosideros polymorpha  var. glaberrima
2       Gahnia     aspera    globosa                        Gahnia aspera subsp. globosa
3       Acacia        koa                                                     Acacia koa
```

Comment: This also works and has the added benefit of not having the white space. Thank you @AndrewGB